# How to set layout, base class and usings for all views?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 5, I can set a default base class and usings for all views in "Views/Web.Config":

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="SomeCustomPageClass">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="SomeNamespace" />
```

I can also set the default layout for all views in "_ViewStart.cshtml":

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SomeCustomLayout.cshtml"; }
```

How can I do any of these in MVC 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reported [in this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1109) in CTP3 there is no way of doing this via configuration. You can however replace the default MvcRazorHost with a custom one:

```
public abstract class MyPage<T> : RazorPage<T>
{/*...*/}

public abstract class MyPage : RazorPage
{/*...*/}

public class MvcMyHost : MvcRazorHost
{
    public MvcMyHost() : base(typeof(MyPage).FullName) { }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IBuilder app)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
        configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        app.UseServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvc(configuration);
            services.AddTransient<IMvcRazorHost, MvcMyHost>();
        });
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you don't get intellisense with this approach, since the editor always uses the original MvcRazorHost class.

In `alpha4` of vNext everything you've asked for (page base type via - @inherits directive, usings, layout) will be supported via `_ViewStart.cshtml` as discussed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/881).

Comment: Same for usings and `_ViewStart`?

Comment: @ŞafakGür just drop a _ViewStart.cshtml file into the /Views folder and add the layout directive. I tried it out in the default CTP3 webapp, by deleting all this.Layout = "..." directives from the views, and it seems to work.

Comment: Note that many of the reasons to replace the base class (like add properties, change HtmlHelper and so on) are now unnecessary with the new @inject directive. You can inject a service into your page and Razor will code generate a property that replaces the original property, or adds a new one.

Comment: `MvcRazorHost` is gone. The linked issue and the whole project is also gone.

Answer (score 0):

as of 2017-1-14, the documentation on [Razor Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor#directives) says this is supported:

> The `@inherits` directive gives you full control of the class your Razor page inherits

```
@inherits TypeNameOfClassToInheritFrom
```

> For instance, let’s say we had the following custom Razor page type:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

public abstract class CustomRazorPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{
    public string CustomText { get; } = "Hello World.";
}
```

> The following Razor would generate `<div>Custom text: Hello World</div>`.

```
@inherits CustomRazorPage<TModel>

<div>Custom text: @CustomText</div>
```

Comment: That sets in for one view. In particular, the general base class will be a generic and each view will have a different model.